# cannot declare field ‘Executive::history’ to be of abstract type

Tags: c++, compiler-errors, abstract-class

I have read some other post about this error and have seen the popular problem is there are pure virtual methods in the objects class but I don't have any that I can see. 
The error message is `executive.h:13:44: error: invalid new-expression of abstract class type ‘List<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char> >’`

This is the executive.h

```
private:
    string command="";
    List<string>* history = new List<string>();
    int currentPosition=0;

public:
    Executive(string filename);
    ~Executive();
    void navigateTo(string url);

    void forward();

    void back();

    string current() const;

    void copyCurrentHistory(List<string>& destination);

    void printHistory();
```

The List.h

```
template <class T>
class List: public ListInterface<T>{    
private:
    int length;
    Node<T>* head= nullptr;

public:
    List();
    ~List();
    bool isEmpty() const;

    int getLength() const;

    void insert(int newPosition, const T& newEntry) ;

    void remove(int position) ;

    void clear();

    T getEntry(int position);

    void setEntry(int position, const T& newEntry);

    Node<T>* getNode(int postion);
```

And my the class where the pure virtual methods are listInterface.h

```
template<class T>
class ListInterface
{    
public:


     virtual ~ListInterface() {}
     virtual bool isEmpty() const = 0;
     virtual int getLength() const = 0;
     virtual void insert(int newPosition, const T& newEntry) = 0;
     virtual void remove(int position) = 0;
     virtual void clear() = 0;
     virtual T getEntry(int position) const = 0;
     virtual void setEntry(int position, const T& newEntry) = 0;
```

I am also getting a note from my compiler saying this but I don't make since because it says its the line where my class name is.

```
list.h:11:7: note:   because the following virtual functions are pure within ‘List<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char> >’:
 class List: public ListInterface<T>{
```

Comment: It's quite obvious that this is not the actual compilation error. If you compare, one by one, abstract methods in the base class, with the implementation in the subclass, you will find exactly one method whose signature does not match. Your homework assignment is to learn how to use the `override` keyword, which will catch this common error in a much more obvious way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`T getEntry(int position);` is not an implementation for `virtual T getEntry(int position) const = 0;`. Add `const` to method's signature.